# Ordered list with images to the right of each list item

Tags: html, html-lists

I would like to create an ordered list with a few icons to the left of each list item.  I would like the layout to look like this

```
<image1><image2> 1. Lorem Ipsum
<image2><image2> 2. Lorem Ipsum
<image3><image2> 3. Lorem Ipsum
```

I can easily place the images to the right of the list item text, but I cannot seem to get it to be aligned to the left of each number in the ordered list.

Comment: give us your code so we can see what are you doing wrong

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle of your code containing your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [Updated Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/wmky4/1/).

**The HTML:**

```
<ol class="img">
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ol>
```

**The CSS:**

```
ol.img li{background: url("http://www.siguccs.org/Conference/Fall2007/images/icon_bullet.gif") no-repeat scroll 1px 5px transparent;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 16px;}
```

Comment: You have `img` elements directly within your `ol`... permitted contents for an `ol` are _zero or more `li` elements_: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html

Comment: oops. Sorry I was in hurry. I have updated my solution - @canon

Comment: I hope you are satisfied with the solution - @LukasH

Comment: This looks like it might be a solution, but is it possible to have more than one image?

Comment: It is possible, if you add spans and apply the classes with background images. You can take my answer as a hint and try the solution. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the solutions is simple and it should be something like this:

```
<ol>
<table>
<tr>
<td><image1 /></td>
<td><li>Lorem Ipsum</li></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><image2 /></td>
<td><li>Lorem Ipsum</li></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><image1 /></td>
<td><li>Lorem Ipsum</li></td>
</tr>
</table>
</ol>
```

i didnt tested yet, i just wrote the code directly here so give it a try...

The solution is basically to put each image and a text in a row in a table....

Answer (score 0):

A solution with :before pseudo-elements in css:

```
    li {
    position: relative;
}
li:before {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -40px;
    background: url(http://www.hadley.edu/images/RightTriangleIcon.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/poselab/Qcejy/